# Fast HDFS and Hive data replication

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, replication

I'm considering data repication between clusters for 2 use cases :

1. DR (so replication between 2 data centers
2. Sync between 2 production clusters

For first one, I'd tend to think Falcon is the right option. But for second one, I want to replicate data as sson as it is available (means end of put for HDFS, and end of table creation for Hive). What would be your view on this ?

Comment: My view is that Hadoop is not a real time system. If you need immediate reads for every write between two separate systems, you need a highly consistent database. Hive nor HDFS are databases

Comment: Guess my req is unclear. It's basically replacting data between 2 clusters, not having immediate reads/write from the system. It's really Hadoop to Hadoop. Eg. Job ends on cluster 1, then immediatly replicate on cluster 2...

Comment: Use Oozie to schedule the job, then a distcp action. It won't be "fast" depending on the data sizes

Comment: So basically, programmatic, using distcp for hdfs and sqoop for hive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered ReAir https://github.com/airbnb/reair

Seems a good tools to look at. :)